# Amazon Route 53 - cofigure redirect to an onpremises public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have a web site hosted within Elastic Beanstalk environment in Amazon AWS cloud.
It is secured with an SSL certificate obtained through external service and imported into AWS environment.

It is required now that this site is migrated to an on-premises environment. We want to configure the Route 53 DNS configuration for the domain to redirect to the on-premise server (after public DNS configuration has been changed) in order to avoid some temporal DNS resolve issues.

Is that possible and how?

My current Route 53 configuration is shown below and I'm wondering if only changing the ALIAS record to point to the on-premises IP is going to fix things:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure smooth migration from AWS hosted to self hosted, ensure the website is up and running on both places simultaneously. 
After that  -

1. reduce the DNS ttl of the A record to 60 second, wait until the previous ttl time atleast. (this is to ensure new dns changes propagation happens quickly.)
2. After that change the DNS entry to point to on premise IP.
3. Your users should be now accessing the on-premise hosted website.
4. Verify everything and set the desired TTL.

If you are using route53 A record with Alias set to yes, than you can skip step 1, and you need to set alias to no.

Comment: So this means that no changes within the Route 53 configuration are required, only at the domain registrar, right? In Route 53 we have TTL only for NS and SOA records. Would it be a problem if we set those records for 1min also? ... dns is not my strength

Comment: no changes required at domain registrar, only in route53 change the A record , set alias to no, and than add the ip of the on-premises and set ttl to 60.